# Background Notification when Application is Launched

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

Can an application running in the background on an iOS device be notified when a different application (i.e. Phone, Safari, etc.) is launched? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simply no.

2 reasons:

- In the background state apps can do very little, compared to the foreground, they can only do one of several predefined things, such as registering for location (GPS) updates, playing audio, task completion (user quits app during save/upload, the app will continue to save/upload), VOIP and that's about it.
- Apps have their own sandbox, app to app communication is very limited.

There is no API to do this, unless you are wanting the app to be available for jailbroken devices.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the fast response!